# How to call a function when a page loads in Javascript with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pageload

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        function getDetails() {
            var IDex = getQueryStringVariableByName("GameID");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http:/...",
                data: "{'ItemID': '" + escape(IDex) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = response.d;
                    $('#output').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var str = "Title: " + item.Name + "<br /> Current Price: " + item.CurrentPrice + "<br /> Developer: " + item.Developer + "<br /> Genres: " + item.Genre
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + str + '</li>');
                    });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#output').text(msg);
                }
            });
        }


         function getQueryStringVariableByName(name) {
             //use this function by passing it the name of the variable in the query
             //string your are looking for.  For example, if I had the query string
             //"...?id=1" then I could pass the name "id" to this procedure to retrieve
             //the value of the id variable from the querystring, in this case "1".
             name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
             var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
             var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
             var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
             if (results == null)
                 return "";
             else
                 return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
         }

         window.onload = GetDetails;
         //$(document).ready( function () {
         //    getDetails();
         //
</script>
```

I have tried multiple methods to get getDetails to run when the page loads. I have tried the window.onload method, putting it in the body tag, and a few others but I can't seem to find a way to get it to load automatically.

Comment: i.e because `GetDetails`  != `getDetails` It is case sensitive

Comment: are you sure that jquery is linked as a script ?

Answer (score 1):

it should be getDetails or you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  functionname();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the compiler was actually reading your code when the page loads is

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    getDetails();
});

function getDetails() { 
   alert("this is a try");
   //or
   console.log("this is a try");
}
```

and of course include the jquery framework to your document like

```
<script src = "path" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

The best way to do is write it before you have to close the body tag

Hope it helps!

Comment: The alert is working, so the compiler is working at least. Must be another error.

Comment: Did you check what @PSL had commented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but the way to run a function a after page loads in `jQuery` is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your code goes here..
    myFunction();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work?

```
$(function(){
         getDetails();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   getDetails();
});
```

will work for sure.